# American Standard Freedom 80 Furnace Pilot Ignition Won't Light

Tags: furnace, pilot-light, american-standard

I have an American Standard Freedom 80 Furnace (Model AUD100R936H2) that won't light.  I turn on the thermostat, which works as expected, and the fan kicks on in the unit.  After about a minute I can hear the pilot trying to ignite for 3 or 4 seconds, but it never actually lights.  During this short time I can smell gas, so I know that it at least has gas available.  This model has the automatic ignition so I know I can't try to light it manually.  The red light below is on a constant fast flashing cycle.

I've attached a pic of the starter mechanism.

[image]

What are some further steps on troubleshooting?

Thanks to all who respond!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to call an HVAC Tech, which was a good move.  Turns out that the board was bad and needed completely replaced.